# Notice: Error: Could not load language module/magnorcms! in //system/library/language.php on line 39

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed an opencart theme and you can watch it here:

taswikdz.com

but I have an error in header

> Notice: Error: Could not load language module/magnorcms! in //system/library/language.php on line 39

files are here:

module/magnorcms.php

```
<?php  
class ControllerModulemagnorcms extends Controller {
    protected function index($setting) {
        $this->language->load('module/magnorcms');

        $this->data['heading_title'] = sprintf($this->language->get('heading_title'), $this->config->get('config_name'));

        $get_lan_id = $this->config->get('config_language_id');


        $this->data['magnorcms_header'] = html_entity_decode(isset($setting['headertitle'][$get_lan_id]) ? $setting['headertitle'][$get_lan_id] : '' , ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        $this->data['message'] = html_entity_decode(isset($setting['description'][$get_lan_id]) ? $setting['description'][$get_lan_id] : '' , ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/magnorcms.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/module/magnorcms.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/module/magnorcms.tpl';
        }

        $this->render();
    }
}
?>
```

library/language.php

```
<?php
class Language {
private $default = 'english';
private $directory;
private $data = array();

public function __construct($directory) {
    $this->directory = $directory;
}

public function get($key) {
    return (isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : $key);
}

public function load($filename) {
    $file = DIR_LANGUAGE . $this->directory . '/' . $filename . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $_ = array();

        require($file);

        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $_);

        return $this->data;
    }

    $file = DIR_LANGUAGE . $this->default . '/' . $filename . '.php';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        $_ = array();

        require($file);

        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, $_);

        return $this->data;
    } else {
        trigger_error('Error: Could not load language ' . $filename . '!');
    //  exit();
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: You have a missing language file that you will need to add in 
/catalog/language/your-language-folder/module
The file is magnorcms.php.

Comment: OK, will write an answer for this so that You can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, You have add custom module in your store. So, Language file is missing for it module in your site source. is not available your custom module language file in default OpenCart source.

Most probable reason can be that you are missing one of the following file in your source:

```
catalog/language/your-language-folder/module/magnorcms.php
```

You will need to add `magnorcms.php` file. and, then try.